# Istio ratelimit service returns 503 Service Unavailable on istio version 1-9-9

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Using global istio ratelimit configuration like this example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: catalog-ratelimit-actions
  namespace: istioinaction
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: catalog
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: VIRTUAL_HOST
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
 
        value:
          rate_limits:    ❶
            - actions:
              - header_value_match:
                  descriptor_value: no_loyalty
                  expect_match: false
                  headers:
                  - name: "x-loyalty"
            - actions:
              - header_value_match:
                  descriptor_value: bronze_request
                  headers:
                  - name: "x-loyalty"
                    exact_match: bronze
            - actions:
              - header_value_match:
                  descriptor_value: silver_request
                  headers:
                  - name: "x-loyalty"
                    exact_match: silver
            - actions:
              - header_value_match:
                  descriptor_value: gold_request
                  headers:
                  - name: "x-loyalty"
                    exact_match: gold
```

it works fine on istio version 1-8-6 however it doesnt fly on 1-9-9, cant seem to find the cause for this, has anyone else encountered this? Running latest envoyproxy/ratelimit image

in envoy proxy container logs error complains about unhealthy upstream:

```
[2022-08-22T14:05:18.145Z] "GET /other HTTP/1.1" 503 UH no_healthy_upstream - "-" 0 19 0 - "-" "curl/7.79.1" "22945aea-84cf-4c48-ad53-82ff4672a848" "catalog.namespace" "-" - - 172.20.31.226:80
```

Comment: Does your real config have the `❶` character in it? Looks like invalid yaml.

Comment: ignore that, not related to the issue